# How to implement this (HttpContext) dependency in Unity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, inversion-of-control, unity-container, httpcontext

we have a class with a dependency to the `HttpContext`.
We've implemented it like this:

```
public SiteVariation() : this(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current))
{
}
public SiteVariation(HttpContextBase context)
{}
```

Now what i want to do is to instantiate the `SiteVariation` class via `Unity`, so we can create one constructor.
But i do not know how to configure this new `HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current))` in Unity in the config way.

ps
this is the config way we use

```
<type type="Web.SaveRequest.ISaveRequestHelper, Common" mapTo="Web.SaveRequest.SaveRequestHelper, Common" />
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I wouldn't take a dependency on `HttpContextBase` directly. I would instead create a wrapper around it, and use the bits you need:

```
public interface IHttpContextBaseWrapper
{
   HttpRequestBase Request {get;}
   HttpResponseBase Response {get;}
   //and anything else you need
}
```

then the implementation:

```
public class HttpContextBaseWrapper : IHttpContextBaseWrapper
{
   public HttpRequestBase Request {get{return HttpContext.Current.Request;}}
   public HttpResponseBase Response {get{return HttpContext.Current.Response;}}
   //and anything else you need
}
```

This way, your class now just relies on a wrapper, and doesn't need the actual HttpContext to function. Makes it much easier to inject, and much easier to test:

```
public SiteVariation(IHttpContextBaseWrapper context)
{

}

var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IHttpContextBaseWrapper ,HttpContextBaseWrapper>();
```

Comment: Nice. Was troubled by the wrapper because everything seems to go wrapped these days, but in this case it seems like a good one.

Comment: About the 'everything seems to go wrapped these days': i heard someone say: every year we add new wrappers around the crappy code we've built last year. This has nothing to do with the answer, which is good, but it just came up :-)

Comment: @Michel: There's a lot of truth to that statement. With DI/IoC being the flavor of the day, I've been writing wrappers around lots of "legacy" code (code that in some cases isn't older than a couple of years) to make it more testable. Right now it feels like the right thing to do. In 3 year from now, we'll all be saying "Man, WTF were we thinking with all those one-off interfaces!!"

Comment: .NET is largely a wrapper around Win32... maybe we ought to go back to writing Win32 code. :)

Comment: Microsoft implement a [`HttpContextWrapper`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextwrapper(v=vs.110).aspx) now so you don't need to write your own

Answer (score 40):

Microsoft has already built great wrappers and abstractions around `HttpContext`, `HttpRequest` and `HttpResponse` that is included in .NET so I would definitely use those directly rather than wrapping it myself.

You can configure Unity for `HttpContextBase` by using `InjectionFactory`, like this:

```
var container = new UnityContainer(); 

container.RegisterType<HttpContextBase>(new InjectionFactory(_ => 
    new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)));
```

Additionally, if you need `HttpRequestBase` (which I tend to use the most) and `HttpResponseBase`, you can register them like this:

```
container.RegisterType<HttpRequestBase>(new InjectionFactory(_ => 
    new HttpRequestWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Request)));

container.RegisterType<HttpResponseBase>(new InjectionFactory(_ => 
    new HttpResponseWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Response)));
```

You can easily mock `HttpContextBase`, `HttpRequestBase` and `HttpResponseBase` in unit tests without custom wrappers.

Comment: Your answer is great, so this is purely a stylistic alternative: because you're returning a simple object in a lamda you don't need a formal code block.  So you can simply write it one line:

container.RegisterType<HttpContextBase>(new InjectionFactory(c => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)));

Comment: @BlackjacketMack Thanks! Yes, I like that better. I have updated the answer with this. To follow convention, I also updated to use underscore to indicate that the parameter is not used.

Comment: Nice.  That's the first time I've seen the underscore convention but I like it!  Very communicative.